# Makefile "run" yields error but manual exec does not

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

The program executes without error when executing the binary manually. Does anyone know what is wrong with this makefile or source code that would make the command "make run" yield an error:

[image]

Here is the makefile:

```
# QuickSelect
# Author Nick Gallimore
EXE=QuickSelect

GCC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++17

.PHONY : all
all: $(EXE)

# QuickSelect
.PHONY : run
run : QuickSelect
    @./QuickSelect

QuickSelect : QuickSelect.cpp
    $(GCC) $^ $(CFLAGS) -o $@

# clean
.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm -f $(EXE)
```

Here is the source code:

```
// Author Nick Gallimore
// See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int partition(int list[], int left, int right, int pivotIndex) 
{
    int pivotValue = list[pivotIndex];

    int tmp = list[pivotIndex];
    list[pivotIndex] = list[right];
    list[right] = tmp;

    int storeIndex = left;
    for (int i = left; i < right - 1; i++) 
    {
        if (list[i] < pivotValue) 
        {
            tmp = list[storeIndex];
            list[storeIndex] = list[i];
            list[i] = list[storeIndex];

            storeIndex++;
        }
    }

    tmp = list[right];
    list[right] = list[storeIndex];
    list[storeIndex] = list[right];
    return storeIndex;
}

int select(int list[], int left, int right, int k) 
{
    if (left == right)
    {
        return list[left];
    }

    int pivotIndex = right;

    pivotIndex = partition(list, left, right, pivotIndex);

    if (k == pivotIndex)
    {
        return list[k];
    }
    else if (k < pivotIndex) 
    {
        return select(list, left, pivotIndex - 1, k);
    }
    else 
    {
        return select(list, pivotIndex + 1, right, k);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    // init array with random values
    int array[] = {4, 341, 123, 5634, 23, 356, 2887, 76, 45};
    auto result = select(array, 0, sizeof(array[0] / sizeof(*array)), 1);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: 1) What is the sequence of events, when it fails to rebuild `QuickSelect`? Do you modify the source code before you run Make? 2) That's very strange, could you post a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: So the problem does actually have to do with the source code not being changed. I'm just dumb. But I will re-word the question to now be: why does this program execute normally when ran with ./QuickSelect yet "make run" yields an error. Edited to add source code. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return result;
```

Your code returns the result (4) as the exit code of your program. Nonzero exit codes are conventionally interpreted as "error during the execution of the program"; make notices that your program exited with 4 and aborts, printing your exit code as error.